# Multi-level approval workflow in c# with sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, development, approval

I am new to Sharepoint development and have a task to implement a 3-step approval workflow in C#.

User uploads some document [**status=review**], goes for the approval to his/her Manager and on Manager's approval gets sent to PM [**status=approved**]. When PM finally approves this document, [**status=completed**] and the workflow is completed.

**Understood:**

1. I have to create a document library that will be associated with the workflow that I will create. This part is done and a part of my workflow code is implemented.

**Queries:**

1. Where should I maintain the approver's list? Should I create a document library and how will they approve the documents?
2. For the document library associated with my workflow, upon document upload by a user [**Step-1**], how can I change the status of the workflow to **[status=review]**. Here I don't want to give the option to the user to change the status. As the workflow moves from **Step-1 to Step-2**, the workflow status will be updated automatically.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: approver's comments can be a splist separately OR as a separate metadata in the same doc lib. based on the roles , you show/hide the columns/fields in the appropriate screen. you create a column called "approvers comments" as multiline text and add it in the doc lib and show only when the approver's screen is populated and hide when the requestor submits the document.

Comment: @prasadwt Any reference materials you could suggest?

Comment: this is a  common scenario in any DMS system implemented by sharepoint. you can get lot of materials in internet, just google it.also you can search in social msdn sharepoint forums as well. using the sharepoint designer workflow and making custom views and using the CSOM in the js file this can be achieved. using c# is ok, but you can achieve this using CSOM/JSOM as well. use js file and write the CRUD operations,while  uploading the document int the doc lib and update the status columns in the doc lib columns - as metadata fields-and  refer these js files from a content editor web part.

Comment: create approvalformNew.html and approvalformdisp.html approvalformEdit.html and  put these files in site assets library. and create the approvalformNew.aspx,approvalformEdit.aspx,approvalformDisp.aspx using the sp designer , when populating these pages, the code in the content editor web part will redirect it to html/js file and in turn it will execute the jsm/csom code for CRUD operations. Either you can use site columns or doc lib columns or use custom content types that contains these status, other metadata fields. using the custom content type also, you can show / hide the views.